# Cisco CIMC "forgets" settings on power loss

Tags: cisco, remote-access, lom

I have a Cisco UCS C200 M2 server, and CIMC forgets every setting(which NIC to use, IP settings, admin password, etc)when the server is unplugged. I replaced the CMOS battery on the motherboard, and it didn't solve the problem.